# How to click form button via HttpWebRequest?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest to access page.  That is working.  But I need to click one of two form submit buttons on this page.  Each button has unique name and id values.  The form tag has no URL specified.  But I know that manually clicking a button works fine.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what the processing script (form action) is expecting as part of the button click (field names and values) and what http method to use (GET, POST, etc) - then construct a proper HttpRequest.

Fiddler can help greatly in figuring all that out.

Comment: I don't see anything about the http method being used via Fiddler.  Do you have a link to anything explaining how to view that in Fiddler?

Comment: Click on a session and look at the request headers, or raw request

Comment: But you don't even need fiddler for that.  Just view source on the page you want and look at the form tag.